# Is it OK/possible to modify instance variables inside an enum declaration?

Tags: java, dynamic, enums, instance

Or, to re-phrase it: can enum types be "mutable"?

```
public enum Foo {
    ONE,TWO;

    private String bar;

    Foo() { this.bar = ""; }
    String bar() { return bar; }

    // legal?
    void bar(String bar) { this.bar = bar; }
}
```

I guess if I want to modify it, it's no longer an enum type.

Thoughts?

Comment: I saw this post.  He's probably right.  [link](http://binkley.blogspot.com/2006/11/java-enum-misuse.html)

Comment: it compiles.  But again, aren't enum types supposed to be immutable?  How come Java lets me do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's absolutely valid. It's just a really bad idea. Callers are likely to *expect* the enum to be properly immutable. In some cases you might want to make it "appear" to be immutable, e.g. with caching, while still mutating the internal variables... but that's very much an edge case.

As to why Java lets you do this... even if it forced all member variables to be final, that wouldn't make enum values *truly* immutable... for example, you could have a `List<String>` which was modified each time you called a particular method...

Fundamentally, Java's not very good at enforcing immutability.