# Java Collections: IF the key of Hashmap is Immutable Object then do we need to override hashcode and equals?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap, equals, hashcode

I am getting confused with one concept. Can someone please throw some light on it.

Question: If the key of `Hashmap` is Immutable Object(create by developer) then do we need to override `hashcode()` and `equals()`? Or having immutable field as key solves the problem of overriding `hashcode()` and `equals()`?

Thanks.

Comment: Is it possible that you'll store an object using one key, and then try to retrieve it using a key which is an identical object, but not the same object?

Comment: Then if you don't override hashCode and equals, your map can't know that the key you use to retrieve is identical to the key you used when you stored the object, so it won't find the object that you stored.

Answer (score 4):

Yes. I'll cite the example of `java.lang.Integer` here. If we wish to have a (sparse) mapping of integers to objects, we'd use something along the lines of `HashMap<Integer, Object>`. If we add an entry `Integer.valueOf(2)=>"foo"`, and try to retrieve it with `new Integer(2)` then the overridden hashcode and equals are required.

Answer (score 1):

These are slightly different categories of issues.

As in [hexafraction's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23639889/1426891), having immutable instances is not sufficient to let you skip the step of writing an `equals` and `hashCode`, if two different instances could ever be considered to be the same. `new Integer(2)` should always be equal to every other `new Integer(2)`, even though the objects are immutable and the instances are different.

That said, there are examples of "instance-controlled classes" where the default behavior of *instance identity* is enough:

- Enum instances are created at compile time, one per value. There is (theoretically) no way to produce any other instance. If no two instances are equal, the default implementation of `equals` and `hashCode` is sufficient. [Enum instances aren't compiler-guaranteed to be immutable, but you should treat them as such.](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5082227/1426891)
- If your class's instances are guaranteed to be different from one another, regardless of whether they're immutable, you can skip `equals` and `hashCode`. One could imagine a Car object, where every Car that a CarFactory produces is different.
- As a variation of the above, if you control object instantiation tightly enough that equal representations are always given the exact same instance, then that could be considered sufficient:

  ```
  public class MyClass {
    private MyClass(int foo) { /* ... */ }

    private static final Map<Integer, MyClass> instanceCache = new HashMap<>();

    /** Returns an existing MyClass(foo) if present; otherwise, creates one. */
    public synchronized static MyClass create(int foo) {
      // Neither leak-proof or thread-safe. Just demonstrating a concept.
      if (instanceCache.contains(foo)) {
        return instanceCache.get(foo);
      }
      MyClass newMyClass = new MyClass(foo);
      instanceCache.put(foo, newMyClass);
      return newMyClass;
    }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Try it and see:

```
public class OverrideIt
{
    static class MyKey
    {
        public final int i; // immutable
        public MyKey(int i)
        {
            this.i = i;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Map<MyKey, String> map = new HashMap<MyKey, String>();
        map.put(new MyKey(1), "Value");
        String result = map.get(new MyKey(1));
        System.out.println(result);  // null
    }
}
```

which prints out `null`, showing that we failed to look up our value. This is because the two copies of `MyKey` are not equal and don't have the same hashcode, because we did not override `.equals()` and `hashcode()`.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, it's not indeterminate.  Even if the hash codes work out the same, you're keying by a different object.  This will always return null.  I apologise for my error.

Answer (score 0):

Facts

1. Basic data structure for hashMap is `Entry[]` (Entry is kind of LinkedList).
2. Key's hashcode used to locate the position in this Array
3. Once the Entry retried using hashcode then Key's Equal used to pick the correct Entry (By Iterating hasNext)
4. Default hashcode returns unique Integer value for that instance.

And you Agreed in comment section

```
 "Is it possible that you'll store an object using one key, 
  and then try to retrieve it using a key which is an identical object,
  but not the same object"
```

Even though both keys having same value the instances are different. then you might have different hashcode for both keys as per contract (Fact 4) . Thus you will have different position in array (Rule 2)

`map.put(new key(1),"first element");`

Here key Object does not override so it will return hashcode unquie per instance. (to avoid too complication assume the hashcode returned as 000025 . So Entry[25] is "First Element" )

map.get(new key(1))

Now this new key may return hashcode value as `000017` , So it would try to get value from Entry[17]  and return null ( which is not excepted) .

**Note I just gave sample as 000025 and 000017 for simplicity , actually hashmap would revisit the hashcode and change it based on array size**

So far we have not discussed weather the Key is Mutable or Immutable . Irrespective of the key is Mutable or Immutable

```
If you store an object using one key,and then try to retrieve it using a key 
which is an identical object,but not the same object
```

You need to override the hashcode and make sure it returns the same Integer , so that it would locate same bucket (position in Array) and get the element. Same applies to equals to get the correct element from Entry